# Remember checked checkboxes in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have a DataGridView where the first column is a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn. The user checks some checkboxes to indicate which items are to be deleted.

When I hide the form and reload it, I need the DataGridView to remember which checkboxes were checked.

Comment: you need to save your checkbox column state in a static list

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following post and update the question appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the changes at least at the point where you close your Form (if you just hide it, why reload then?).
The way I usually work this out is listening to the Dgv's CellEndEdit event:

```
SomeDataGridView.CellEndEdit += ObjectPropertyChanged
```

then in the Callback you can get the Object back by using the "DataBoundItem" prop of the Dgv and process / save it however you need:

```
protected virtual void ObjectPropertyChanged(object sender, DataGridViewVellEventArgs e)
{
  var selectedObject = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
  //Assuming you stored in a List and each Object has an ID as prop:
  var indx = _Objects.IndexOf(_Objects.Where(o => o.ID.Equals(selectedObject.ID)))
  _Objects.Remove(indx)
  _Objects.Insert(indx, selectedObject)
}
```

You could also do database update, write to a text-file, save in configuration, ...